# Dataloader v55 quickly flashes open and closes

Tags: data-loader

I downloaded the latest version of dataloader, version 55.0.1, and installed the latest version of the JDK:

`openjdk 18.0.1 2022-04-19`

`OpenJDK Runtime Environment Zulu18.30+11-CA (build 18.0.1+10)`

`OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM Zulu18.30+11-CA (build 18.0.1+10, mixed mode, sharing)`

I was running version 54 which had been running fine but I started having trouble logging into a sandbox org, so I updated to version 55.0.1 and now it won't fully open.

Anyone have any idea what might be causing this issue or how I can debug it so see what is causing the issue? I've tried removing the re-installing several times.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [sdl.log](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.dataLoader.meta/dataLoader/loader_troubleshooting.htm) file can help you debug this. It's in `%TEMP%\sdl.log` on Windows, and `$TMPDIR/sdl.log` on MacOS. Since you're getting as far as a window opening, you should get some useful information in this log.

Comment: The only info I'm getting in the sdl.log is the following: `""2022-08-07 13:27:17,954 INFO  [main] controller.Controller initLog (Controller.java:472) - The log has been initialized` then the log ends

Comment: @Dman100 try running the data loader binary from a terminal or command prompt, then. You'll probably see a have crash log, I'm betting.

Comment: I did get a better output of the failure after trying to run from the command line. I got the following error: Could not find or load main class Files\Zulu\zulu-18\bin\   
I checked my environmental variables and the JAVA_HOME path looks correct and I added a CLASSPATH to the lib\*.jar as well.

Comment: @Dman100 hmm. You might try uninstalling and reinstalling Java, also make sure the bin is in your PATH environment variable.

Comment: well, after removing the environmental variables for Java and then re-adding just the path variable it fixed the issue. The path was exactly the same as it was before. I did remove the JAVA_HOME variables, but those were pointing to the same location minus the bin folder. I'm not quite sure why it broke. Thanks for your suggestions. It helped me track down the issue!

Comment: Hi @Dman100 can you please explain in details how you have fix by doing changes in environment variables I am facing the same issue

Comment: Hi @SalmanDalal sorry, I just saw your message. What I did was remove the JAVA_HOME variable for both my User variable section and system variable section. I also removed the the directory location to Java in the Path user variable and system variable sections. Then re-added the Path to only the system variable section. The path for Java in my system was C:\Program Files\Zulu\zulu-18\bin. It probably is different in your system. I only have the path to Java defined in my system variable section for my environmental variables.

Comment: Ok let me check on this

Answer (score 1):

On Windows, v55.0.1 actually appears to have a syntax error in its batch file. Line 45:

```
    PATH="%JAVA_HOME%"\bin\;%PATH%;
```

If I edit the quotes out of the line it's fixed.