# Data loader opens and closes on mac

Tags: data-loader, admin

Installed data loader on Mac with Big Sur (older than 2021 so rosetta no supported)

Installed the Azul as well. It opens and then quickly closes again.

Have deleted and reinstalled again - no luck.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Have you tried checking the [log files](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.dataLoader.meta/dataLoader/loader_troubleshooting.htm)? If you can spot a specific error, that would help us troubleshoot the problem. Also, check your Java version, you may an old version installed.

Answer (score 0):

You should run the data loader binary from the terminal or use command prompt. You will get the crash log.

The [sdl.log](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.dataLoader.meta/dataLoader/loader_troubleshooting.htm) file can help you debug this. It's in %TEMP%\sdl.log on Windows, and $TMPDIR/sdl.log on MacOS. Since you're getting as far as a window opening, you should get some useful information in this log.

Reference :- [Dataloader v55 quickly flashes open and closes](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/382446/dataloader-v55-quickly-flashes-open-and-closes)